# I want to know about alphabets using map?

Tags: python-3.x

why we use this particular range from 97 to 123? And I want to know more about alphabets using map ?
**list(map(chr,range(97,123)))**

Answer (score 0):

`ASCII` codes for the lower case English alphabets range from 97 to 122.

The [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function in the line you provided above, creates an iterable object with the elements from 97 to 122. You are mapping these with the `chr` method. This method returns the associated ASCII character. For example,

```
>>> chr(97)
'a'
>>> chr(100)
'd'
>>> chr(122)
'z'
```

Now, your [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function doing all these operations for the numbers between 97 to 123.

```
>>> map(chr,range(97,123))
<map object at 0x000002EEAE8F46C8>
```

But the `map` returns the map object, and to convert that to a list , you can use `list` method.

```
>>> list(map(chr,range(97,123)))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Regards